# How to reduce .so file size during build with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I build app with android studio, but the created .so file size is a little large. I can add strip flag in file android.mk to remove symbols,

```
cmd-strip = $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)strip --strip-debug -x $1
```

but android studio auto created file android.mk.  I do it in build.gradle, such as add flag cFlags.

```
ndk{
   moduleName "modulexxx"
   abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "mips", "mips64", "x86", "x86_64"
   stl        "stlport_static"
   cFlags      "-std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -s"
}
```

but the .so file' size not become smaller, why?